# How can I have a CSS work only when I have two classes together using less?

Tags: css, less

I have a `<div>` in my application.  It is set to have a class of "`enumPanel`" and dynamically I add the class "`current`".

How can I wire this up in less so that my properties will come into effect only when both classes are present on the div ?

```
.enumPanel .current {
   // this does not seem to work
}
```

Comment: `.enumPanel.current` mind the gap.

Comment: You are currently using a descendant selector. Instead use multiple selector as answered by Yoshi and Curt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.enumPanel.current {}
```

**LESS**

```
.enumPanel {
   &.current {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.enumPanel.current {
    // this will work
}
```